# webapp2 incomplete cookie retrieval

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, http-headers, webapp2

Right before cookie retrieval, printing the headers (on server side, using Python) yields, showing only the 'Cookie' portion:

```
'Cookie': 'clist={%22config_dict%22:{%22OSLO%22:{%22cstate%22:%22EXP%22}}%2C%22table_order%22:[%22OSLO%22]}'
```

However, after `clist_str = self.request.cookies.get('clist')` and printing `clist_str`, the cookie value is cut off like so:

```
{%22config_dict%22:{%22OSLO%22:{%22cstate%22:%22EXP%22}}%2C%22table_order%22:
```

For the sake of readability, for what it's worth, the expected cookie value is:

```
{"config_dict":{"OSLO":{"cstate":"EXP"}},"table_order":["OSLO"]}
```

but we get

```
{"config_dict":{"OSLO":{"cstate":"EXP"}},"table_order":
```

instead.

Any ideas as to how this problem can be solved? The complete cookie is in the request header, but webapp2 doesn't seem to be able to retrieve the cookie correctly. As a side note, the cookie can be set and get successfully on the client-side using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The cookie was URL encoded.  Try this:

```
import urllib
clist_str = urllib.unquote(clist_str)
```

If the cookie is still truncated, it may be a bug in webapp2.  It looks like it breaks on square brackets: `[]`.  You may have to extract the cookie directly from the header instead of using the `cookies` attribute.

Comment: I am aware of this and have the unquote code right after getting the cookie and right before json.loads(). Resorted to a custom get_cookie() method instead as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816196/how-to-get-cookies-values-on-google-app-engine-template. Could be a bug in webapp2.