# Setting a Cookie on a browser using Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies

I have a project I'm working on. I would like to set a cookie when a user logs in so that they will be remembered. However I have tried every method on the internet, all the way from Google to Stack Overflow. I just cant seem to find a method that works.

I have tried:

```
class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        print "Set-Cookie: testing=test123cookie"
        print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
```

And that didnt work. Then tried:

```
import Cookie

class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
        cookie['lastvisit'] = "test"
        print cookie
        print 'Content-Type: text/html\n'
```

And surprise surprise, it doesn't work either. What do I do? How do I do it? I am sure I am just being stupid and not doing something right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`set_cookie()` method](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#full-featured-response-object):

```
class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.set_cookie('lastvisit', 'test', max_age=360, path='/')
```

Comment: And to retrieve a cookie: `self.request.cookies.get("lastvisit")` (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/11816196/328817).